# How can I allow users to run a website without adding its bin folder to SVN?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, svn

When creating a visual studio solution and committing it to SVN, I usually place an `svn:ignore` on all bin folders, as this is avoids conflicts when other users need to work with the same solution.

However, recently I have had a scenario where one or two users need to work with the website project (to be able to amend the website's static files) within the solution but independently of visual studio, e.g. via WebMatrix. This means that they cannot run the solution and they cannot build the website to draw in the dependencies and references. These users can only run the website directly. So I have resolved to re-adding the website's bin folder to SVN but obviously now that results in the previously mentioned conflicts.

Are there any other alternatives to this that would result in minimal annoyance for these users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was straightforward, and I was overthinking the problem. I have just created a .bat file that builds the web project:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "website.csproj" /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Given that each user will have to be running Windows, .Net 4 and WebMatrix already, running this script to build the website is about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need Visual Studio to build the solution.  For example I use Ruby with rake tools to build .Net solution files using the Albacore gem.

read..
http://rake.rubyforge.org/ and https://github.com/Albacore/albacore

This gem is extremely powerful, you can use it to build, run tests and even deploy your website, all without even opening Visual Studio.  It enables you to use any text editor to modify the files.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the users would have to install Ruby on their machines? That is a faff I'd rather avoid for the users, especially if they don't know what they're doing. Plus it is something that each new user working on the project would have to install.